# iPad is not present the "view as" section in the storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

iPad is not present in the size inspector of storyboard. This is the section located in the lower left side which can show you how the View Controller will look like on different size phones.

However it shows other devices. Can someone tell me how I can add iPad?

Comment: Is your project Universal?

Comment: Make your project for Universal devices.

Comment: can you run it on ipad simulator? If not then check your project settings to see if your app is set to run on iphone only or universal...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Find the xcodeproj file in the Project Navigator on the left side of the screen. Then Under Deployment Info -> Devices, pick `Universal` from the dropdown.

Comment: I tried that, returned back to the story board and I still cant see the iPad

Comment: have you tried restarting Xcode and then Product -> Clean?

Comment: @monekypox121 did you disable auto layout in storyboard?